# Azure Data Factory: append array to array in ForEach

Tags: azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory pipeline, I have **ForEach1** loop over Databricks Activities. Those Databricks Activities output arrays of different sizes. I would like to union and pass those arrays to another **ForEach2** loop so that every element of every array would be an item in this new **ForEach2** loop.

How could I collect output arrays from **ForEach1** into one big array? I've tried **Append Variable** Activity, but got the following error:

```
    The value of type 'Array' cannot be appended to the variable of type 'Array'. 
The action type 'AppendToArrayVariable' only supports values of types 'Float, Integer, String, Boolean, Object'.
```

Is there a way to union/merge arrays inside **ForEach1** loop? Or are there any other ways to pass arrays to **ForEach2** where each element of each array would be considered as a separate item and **ForEach2** would loop over each item?

Comment: Hey @Mirit, can you please tell if the final array would have any duplicate values?

Comment: @SaideepArikontham-MT, no, there is no duplicate values in the final array. And across all the arrays of ForEach1 all the values are unique too. No two similar values even if we consider two different arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There is a collection function called `union()` in Azure data factory which takes 2 arguments (both of type array or object). This can be used to achieve your requirement. You can follow the following example which I have tried with `Get Metadata` activity instead of `Databricks Notebook` activity.

- I have a container called `input` and there are 2 folders `a and b` in it. These folders have some files. Using the similar approach, I am appending the array of child items (file names) generated by `Get Metadata` activity in each iteration to get a list of all file names (one big array). The following is my folder structure inside which files are present:

[image]

- First I used `get metadata` to get names of folders inside container.

[image]

- I used `@activity('folder_names').output.childItems` for items value in `ForEach` activity. Now Iniside for each, I have again used `get metadata` to get child items of each folder (I created a dataset and gave dynamic value for folder name in path).

**You can use the procedure from below to get the requirement:**

- I have given the output of the 2nd `get metadata activity` (files in folder) to a `set variable` activity. I created a new variable `current_file_list` (array type) and gave its value as:

```
@union(variables('list_of_files'),activity('files in folder').output.childItems)
```

**Note:** Instead of `activity('files in folder').output.childItems)` in the above union, you can use the array returned by your databricks activity in `Foreach1` for each iteration.

[image]

- The `list_of_files` is another array type variable (created using another `set variable` activity) which is the final array that contains all elements as one big array. I am assigning this variable value as `@variables('current_file_list')`
- This indirectly means that `list_of_files` value is the union of previous array elements and the current folder child item array.

**Reason:** If we use one variable (say list_of_files) and give its value as `@union(variables('list_of_files'),activity('files in folder').output.childItems)` it throws an error. We cannot use self-reference of a variable in azure data factory dynamic content so, we need to create 2 variables to overcome this.

[image]

- When I debug the pipeline, it gives expected output, and we can see the output produced after each activity.

The following are the output images:

- Input for `list of files in current folder` first iteration will be:

[image]

- Input for `list of files in current folder` second iteration will be:

[image]

- Final `list_of_files` array with all elements in single array:

[image]

You can follow the above approach to the combined array and use it for your `ForEach2` activity.